# Rivers (multiline) that belongs to a specific polygon (Sweden)- PostGIS

Tags: postgis, countries

My data are three tables

```
Countries (gid:int, name:char varaying, geo.:geom) 
Cities (gid:int, name:char varaying,admin level: charvar, cntry: char var,port_id:int geo.:geom) 
Rivers (gid:int, name:char varaying, geo.:geom)
```

I must find which rivers (names) are in a specific country (e.g Switzerland)
The folowing SQL gives me only the rivers that comes from neighbor countries and intersected at country's borderline.

```
SELECT rivers.name, countries.name, ST_AsGeoJSON(rivers.geom, 5), ST_AsGeoJSON(countries.geom, 5)
FROM rivers,countries 
WHERE ST_Intersects (countries.geom, rivers.geom) and countries.name='Switzerland';
```

Instead of intersect I also used `ST_contains` and `Within` but I get nothing. That may happens because that this country do not have any river that belong to it entire.
 Do you have any advice on How can I extract the rivers that belong to this country using postgis????

Comment: it seems the `country` geometries are lines and not polygons. The simplest solution would be to have the countries as polygons.

Comment: Thank you fro your reply. Polygons are not lines. The problem was at the river network. I had in my mind an extended river network for this country but the table with the rivers included only the basic river for this country and not all the rivers.  I had to search it earlier.

Comment: That means that ST_Intersection Query gave me  the correct result.